# Can't fetch data, CORS issue, trying to hack it with JSONP, still not working

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, jsonp, axios

I'm trying to fetch data from http://www.recipepuppy.com/api/?q=onion&p=1. (Sample query)

It works in a browser, but I was trying to fetch it inside my React app and I'm encountering `“No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` error.

So I changed my strategy and now I'm trying to use JSONP (https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/blob/master/COOKBOOK.md#jsonp).

But I can't make it work. I'm getting this error all the time. Can someone please help me with my issue?

Error:

*Uncaught ReferenceError: jp0 is not defined
    at ?q=onion&p=1&callback=__jp0:1*

My Code:

```
import jsonp from 'jsonp'

export const FETCH_RECIPES = 'FETCH_RECIPE'
export const SHOW_INFO = 'SHOW_INFO'

export function fetchRecipes (searchTermToDOoooooooooo) {
  const request = jsonp('http://www.recipepuppy.com/api/?q=onion&p=1', null, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.error(err.message)
    } else {
      console.log(data)
    }
  })

  return (dispatch) => {
    /*
    request.then(({ data: data1 }) => {
      dispatch({ type: FETCH_RECIPES, payload: data1 })
    })
    */
  }

}

export function showInfo (info) {
  return {
    type: SHOW_INFO,
    payload: info
  }
}
```

**How that error looks in dev tools:**

[image]

Comment: JSONP only works if the target site understands that. If it just returns with JSON, then JSONP will fail. You'll have to write your own server-side proxy. You can't "hack around" the same-origin policy. *edit* wait; that site does look like it responds with JSONP.  It looks like something's not correctly setting up the global callback.

Comment: Do you have experience using that Axios stuff? I think that's probably where the problem is. It should be creating that global function "jp0" for you, but apparently it isn't.

Comment: @Pointy I don't understand why it isn't. So I should use axios combined with JSONP, right?

Comment: Well JSONP is extremely simple to do: you add `&callback=name` to the end of the URL query and then ensure there's a global function called "name" (can be any name of course).  Then you create a new script tag with the "src" set to that URL, and you add the tag to your page. That's it: when the response comes back, your function will be called. I don't know anything about configuring that library, so I don't know why it's not working for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it with client-only code, at least not with JSONP+Axios ([Axios doesn't (natively) support JSONP](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios/issues/342); the "jsonp" library is different from Axios), because it's the server you're getting information from that's in violation of the cross-origin rules. In this case, it's Recipe Puppy that isn't set up for `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers.

One option is to use a server-side proxy, as @Pointy mentions.

Your flow would then shift to:

1. Client calls server-side proxy for information.
2. Proxy calls Recipe Puppy's API and translates or passes through information as needed.
3. Proxy relays that information to the client-side code for further processing.

As for your current shift to jsonp, it appears the jsonp library is not exporting `jp0` properly for some reason. This could be an error with your build tool. You'll want to double-check your setup and make sure your build tool is picking up the `jsonp` library and actually putting it into the compiled source.

Comment: In this case, as I mentioned in my (updated) comment, that server *does* understand JSONP. I think the problem is in that library the OP is trying to use.

Comment: You don't need `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` for JSONP request

Comment: @Pointy you're right. I've updated my response to take that into account.

Comment: @Shauna, ok, so I need to build this proxy on my own? Something like that?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558977/ajax-cross-domain-call  or like this in node.js: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34685030/server-side-proxy-using-node-js

Comment: That's one way to do it, yes. It's just a simple thing on your server that acts as an intermediary.